# P5.JS Random Walk Always Ends Up On the Top Border

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am learning P5.JS with "The Nature of Code", and trying out the first example code.

https://github.com/nature-of-code/noc-examples-p5.js/tree/master/chp00_introduction/NOC_I_01_RandomWalkTraditional

```js
  let walker;
    
    let bg_color_x = 255;
    let bg_color_y = 51;
    let bg_color_z = 153;
    
    let stroke_color_x = 51;
    let stroke_color_y = 51;
    let stroke_color_z = 204;
    let stroke_weight = 10;
    
    let random_number_for_walking = 5;
    
    function setup() {
      var cnv = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      cnv.style('display', 'block');  
      background(bg_color_x, bg_color_y, bg_color_z);
    
      walker = new Walker();  
    }
    
    
    function draw() {
      walker.step();
      walker.render();
    }
    
    class Walker {
      constructor() {
        this.x = width / 2;
        this.y = height / 2;
      }
    
      render() {
       
        stroke(stroke_color_x, stroke_color_y, stroke_color_z);
        strokeWeight(stroke_weight);    
        point(this.x, this.y);
      }
    
      step() {
        var choice = floor(random(random_number_for_walking));
        if (choice === 0) {
          // this.x++;
          this.x = this.x + stroke_weight;
        } else if (choice == 1) {
          // this.x--;
          this.x = this.x - stroke_weight;      
        } else if (choice == 2) {
          // this.y++;
          this.y = this.y + stroke_weight;      
        } else {
          // this.y--;
          this.y = this.y - stroke_weight;      
        }
        this.x = constrain(this.x, 0, width - stroke_weight);
        this.y = constrain(this.y, 0, height - stroke_weight);
      }
    }
    
    
    function windowResized() {
      resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
      background(bg_color_x, bg_color_y, bg_color_z);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

However, no matter how many times I run it, the art settles at the top of the window. For example, like this.

[image: P5.JS Random Walk Image]

How can I fix this? Is there a way to make it go left or right when it hits one of the four borders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `random_number_for_walking` is wrong!

Your step function has `4` paths:

```
step() {
    var choice = floor(random(random_number_for_walking));

    if (choice === 0) {
        // Right
    } else if (choice == 1) {
        // Left
    } else if (choice == 2) {
        // Down
    } else {
        // Up
    }

    // ...
}
```

But your `random_number_for_walking` is 5 and `random(number)` gives you a number between `[0, number)`, so in your case: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

And if you look closer, you do not handle `choice == 3`, with that `else` you are actually handling `choice == 3 || choice == 4`.

This makes it so its more probable that your `Walker` moves up than down.

Handling correctly the last choice and reducing `random_number_for_walking` to `4` will solve the issue.

Comment: Oh my god, yes! Rookie mistake. That fixed it.